# How to Fetch Token to access APIM from Function App with Managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to access APIM from Azure Function and want APIM to authenticate through Managed Identity Token. I have assigned system assigned identity to the function app.I am following this (sample)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#asal] to generate token. In the below line if I give "https://vault.azure.net" to GetAccessTokenAsync method I am getting the token. but I want the audience to be APIM so I provided https://azure-api.net like mentioned in the last line. but I am getting exception. how can I provide the APIM Url to fetch the access token?

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net");
```

---

```
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://azure-api.net");
```

An Update. I think something wrong with listing the resources. because when I give the proper resource name it says resource doesnt exist in the tenant though I can see the subscription is under the same tenant when I run through az cli.

Comment: You mean you want to call the API protected by Azure AD? Did you configure it as this doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

Comment: Basically I have a policy already in place to validate the token in the APIM side. I am stuck in Function App where I need to generate the token that needs to be passed while calling API though APIM.

Comment: Did you [register an application in Azure AD to represent the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#register-an-application-in-azure-ad-to-represent-the-api)?

Comment: Have given RBAC permission to registered app for the apim ?

Comment: I haven't registered the App, I am using system assigned identity for the Managed Identity,

Comment: I know that, I mean the API side, the managed identity is your client, if you didn't register an AD App, who represents your API?

Comment: right now I am getting the token with the audience managment.azure.com, I am trying to do with user managed identity and registering AD Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need to [Register an application in Azure AD to represent the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#register-an-application-in-azure-ad-to-represent-the-api), then you can get the token for it(i.e. with the `Application ID URI` in the previous link).

```
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("<Application ID URI>");
```

---

Something you need to know:

You can use `azureServiceTokenProvider` to get the token for `https://vault.azure.net`, `https://managment.azure.com`, because they are all the APIs exposed by Microsoft, i.e. [azure keyvault rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/) and [azure management rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/), essentially they are all AD App registered by Microsoft, so if you want to get the token for your own API, you need to register the AD App first to represent the API first.

Also, when you use managed identity to get the token, essentially [it uses the client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token, actually the managed identity is a service principal(i.e. enterprise application) managed by azure. Remember to leverage the [app role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) if you need to validate the `roles` claim when you get the access token.

Comment: I have added the App in AD. I was confused because was not getting the token against the AD App in the local env. after the deployment Function can request one. THanks

Comment: I have a question, is this a bad idea to fetch client credential token against azure management rest api, because for us we don't have a reason to register an AD App and I can see the object ID of the requested function app in the access token which I can validate against.

Comment: @threeleggedrabbit I'm not sure if I understand your meaning correctly, normally, we get different tokens to call different APIs, if you decode the token in https://jwt.io/, you will find they have different audiences. In your case, if you use the token for azure management rest api (its audience is `https://management.azure.com`) to call your own api, I don't think it's a good idea, it is better to register an AD App to represent your own API, then you can use different validate policy in APIM if necessary, leverage e.g. app role.